# OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@AccountID=148))

Tags: sql-server

I recently saw this statement in a large, complex production query that is getting executed a couple hundred times per minute. It seems the original author of this query was trying to optimize the query for when AccountId = 148. There are total of 811 different account Id values that could occur in the table. The value 148 represents 9.5% of all rows in this table (~60.1M rows total) **and has the highest total of any account value**.

I've never come across anyone doing something like this. It seems to me this only has significant value if, more often than not, the @AccountId parameter is equal to 148. Otherwise, the query plan could assume more rows are being returned than actually are. In this case a scan might be performed instead of a seek.

So, is there any practical value to doing this, in this particular scenario?

Comment: I suggest you read this article http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-using-optimize-for-query-hint/

Comment: There could very well be, if account 148 happens to be particularly representative of the distribution/optimal query plan for most other accounts. You want to avoid the optimizer devising a plan for the very first account that gets passed in the query which (say) has no rows associated with it, or very few, causing an inefficient loop join to be locked in that is not appropriate for almost all other values. `OPTIMIZE FOR` is then far preferrable to `RECOMPILE` if the query is executed many times.

Comment: On the other hand, if account 148 is particularly *non* representative of most other accounts but the option was added to speed it up for that account anyway, the correct approach would be custom statistics or a custom index with a filter. Another possible approach that avoids the magic value is `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`, which also avoids issues with a bad distribution for one coincidentally inappropriate parameter value but may or may not yield good execution plans on average.

Comment: Finally (given your edit) optimizing for the *worst* case may seem counterintuitive, but if the worst case happens to have *really bad* execution time otherwise and other cases just become *slightly worse than optimal*, optimizing for it can still make sense. Remember, without `RECOMPILE`, the optimizer must produce *one* plan that works for *all* values (so filtered indexes can't be hit). It better be the plan that works well *over all executions aggregated*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - It seems to me that if the author wanted to optimize for the worst case, a far better approach would have been to create a filtered index on AccountId = 148. In any case, I think I know what I need to do now.. If you type all this up as an answer I'll vote it up and accept it.

Comment: That will not work because the optimizer can't guarantee `AccountID = 148`, so the index can't be used in a general plan. That would only work with `RECOMPILE` (or an `IF`/`ELSE` split to invoke different queries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the extreme case where *only* account 148 covers 10% of the table, and all the other accounts just 0.001% each. Well, given that that account represents 10% of your data, it also stands to reason it will be searched for more often than the other accounts. Now imagine that for *any other account*, a nested loop join over a small amount of rows would be really fast, but for account 148, it would be hideously slow and a hash join would be the superior choice.

Further imagine that by some stroke of bad luck, the first query that comes in to your system after a reboot/plan recycle is one for an account *other* than 148. You are now stuck with a plan that performs extremely poorly 10% of the time, even though it also happens to be really good for other data. In this case, you may well want the optimizer to stick with the plan that isn't a disaster 10% of the time, even if that means it's slightly less than optimal the other times. This is where `OPTIMIZE FOR` comes in.

Alternatives are `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` (if your distribution is far more even, but you need to protect against an accidental plan lock-in from unrepresentative parameters), `RECOMPILE` (which can have a considerable performance impact for queries executed frequently), explicit hints (`FORCESEEK`, `OPTION HASH JOIN`, etcetera), adding fine-grained custom statistics (`CREATE STATISTICS`) and splitting queries (`IF @AccountID = 148 ...`), possibly in combination with a filtered index. But aside from all these, `OPTIMIZE FOR @Param = <specific non-representative value>` certainly has a place.